Replace a single selected character using VBA macro
I want to turn selected asterisk characters into superscripted asterisk.
Selection is important since I don't want to mess up my document completely.
Sub Superstarv4()
' makes all selected asterisks superscripted
    Dim selRange As Range

    ' Check if text is selected
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "No text selected. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set selRange to the selected range
    Set selRange = Selection.Range

    ' Apply formatting only to the selected range
    With selRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "*"  ' Find asterisks
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True  ' Format as superscript
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

If I were to select one (1) asterisk character, it converts ALL of the following asterisk character superscripted in the whole document. This problem consists of all VBA replacement operations. I got similar code that turns commas into dots with the same problem.
There is a quick fix:
Sub Superstarv5()
    ' Check if text is selected
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "No text selected. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Selection.Range

    ' Ensure the range is valid and has text
    If selRange.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Selected text is empty. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Count the number of asterisks in the selected text
    Dim asteriskCount As Long
    asteriskCount = Len(selRange.Text) - Len(Replace(selRange.Text, "*", ""))

    ' Check if there is more than one asterisk
    If asteriskCount <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "Selected text does not contain more than one asterisk. No formatting applied.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Apply superscript formatting only to the selected range
    With selRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "*"  ' Find asterisks
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True  ' Format as superscript
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

This makes sure the user selected two instances of asterisks.

You might not need to use the Find/Replace function if your goal is simply to change the formatting of the selection in Word. Try If Selection.Text = "*" Then: Selection.Font.Superscript = True: End If.

Thank you for taking the time to answer. This would work if I am only selecting asterisks. Selection includes paragraph breaks, other characters, etc., i.e., "Lorem** ipsum dolor." Your code would not work under these conditions.  Only if there is some code that works like If Selection.Text.Has = "*" Then Do This

The main issue in your original code is that the Find operation affects the entire document when only one asterisk is selected. By adding .Wrap = wdFindStop, the search is limited to the selected range only, preventing changes outside the selection. This ensures the macro superscripts only the selected asterisks, no matter how many are present.
Here's the adjusted key part:

.Wrap = wdFindStop ' Stop at the end of the selection


Sub SuperstarFixed()
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Dim n As Long
    Dim CharRange As Range

    Rem Check if text is selected
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "No text selected. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Rem Set selRange to the selected range
    Set SelRange = Selection.Range

    Rem Loop through each character in the selection
    For n = 1 To SelRange.Characters.Count
        Rem Set charRange to each individual character
        Set CharRange = SelRange.Characters(n)

        Rem Check if the character is an asterisk
        If CharRange.Text = "*" Then
            Rem Apply superscript formatting
            CharRange.Font.Superscript = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Thank you for taking your time to answer. Sadly, same with the previous code, this code superscripts all the asterisks that are placed on the rest of the document if I were to select only one instance. I have to select more than one instance to make it work.

I updated ,y answer to iterate over each character.  I think that Find is treating * as a wildcard.

Yep! That solved the issue. But still, I do not understand why the Find operation affects the entire document when only one asterisk is selected.  If Find would treat * as a wildcard, it would superscript every single character. The latest code doesn't have .Wrap in it since it is using another logic than the Find operation, so this solution doesn't specifically answer my question (but fixed my code tho, thank you a LOT).

Thanks for accepting my answer.  One thing that I know for sure is that Ms Word VBA is weird.

Your code is nearly complete. By adding two lines and modifying one, it functions as expected.
Microsoft documentation:

WdFindWrap enumeration (Word)


Find.MatchWildcards property (Word)


Sub Superstarv5()
    ' Check if text is selected
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        MsgBox "No text selected. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Selection.Range

    ' Ensure the range is valid and has text
    If selRange.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Selected text is empty. Please select some text.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Count the number of asterisks in the selected text
    Dim asteriskCount As Long
    asteriskCount = Len(selRange.Text) - Len(Replace(selRange.Text, "*", ""))

    ' Check if there is more than one asterisk
    If asteriskCount <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "Selected text does not contain more than one asterisk. No formatting applied.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print selRange.Characters.Count, asteriskCount
    ' Apply superscript formatting only to the selected range
    With selRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        ' find operation ends if the beginning or end of the search range is reached
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True ' enable wildcards search
        ' escape * as a char
        .Text = "\*"  ' Find asterisks
        .Replacement.Font.Superscript = True  ' Format as superscript
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub


This works too! Thank you for your effort. Even tho I find TinMan's solution simpler with less code, I really appreciate your effort, I learned from it.
